# Why doesn't a KSQL stream not return/show data from messages on topic in broker?

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I've got a simple Kafka broker running with a topic `raw_events`.

With `kafka-console-producer --topic raw_events --broker-list kafka:29092 < event.json` I'm adding events to that topic that successfully show up with `kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server kafka:29092 --topic raw_events`. So, I know the events land in the broker (in the right topic) and can be consumed from the broker**) as well.

In this case, the `event.json` file contains a very simple JSON:

`{'event_type': 'issue',
    'project': 'sample',
    'user': {'name': 'John Doe', 'username': 'jdoe'}
}`

In KSQL, the topic is there:

```
ksql> show topics;

 Kafka Topic           | Registered | Partitions | Partition Replicas | Consumers | ConsumerGroups
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 raw_events            | true       | 1          | 1                  | 3         | 3
```

containing some events from earlier attempts:

```
ksql> print 'raw_events';
Format:STRING
11/2/18 3:36:21 PM UTC , NULL , {'event_type': 'issue', 'project': 'sample', 'user': {'name': 'John Doe', 'username': 'jdoe'}}
11/2/18 3:43:05 PM UTC , NULL , {'event_type': 'issue', 'project': 'sample', 'user': {'name': 'John Doe', 'username': 'jdoe'}}
11/2/18 3:45:19 PM UTC , NULL , {'event_type': 'issue', 'project': 'sample', 'user': {'name': 'John Doe', 'username': 'jdoe'}}
11/2/18 3:45:43 PM UTC , NULL , {'event_type': 'issue', 'project': 'sample', 'user': {'name': 'John Doe', 'username': 'jdoe'}}
11/2/18 3:47:30 PM UTC , NULL , {'event_type': 'issue', 'project': 'sample', 'user': {'name': 'John Doe', 'username': 'jdoe'}}
```

(I'm following https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/developer-guide/create-a-stream.html but with my own data.)

Now, I create a stream in KSQL which succeeds:

```
create stream new_events (event_type varchar, project varchar) with (kafka_topic='raw_events', value_format='JSON');
```

The stream is created:

```
ksql> show streams;

 Stream Name     | Kafka Topic | Format
----------------------------------------
 NEW_EVENTS      | raw_events  | JSON
----------------------------------------
```

Nevertheless (and this is my question / problem -- it could be a PEBKAC or a KSQL error) a `SELECT` on that stream just halts and does not show any events... not even when I continue to add events to the topic:

```
ksql> select * from new_events;
[... nothing here ...]
```

Selecting a specific column like `project` does not return entries either.

---

**) BTW, it is unclear to me why the produce CLI command has an argument `--broker-list` and the consume CLI command has `--bootstrap-server` for seemingly the same thing.

Comment: I think you must define every single field in the JSON Stream for it to be parsed correctly.

Comment: Is it? The `user` field is then an additional challenge, as its contents isn't a 'flat' value but a nested object again. (Trying to parse and query that correctly is my next task - I'm trying the simple case first.) For the time being, I can leave out that field in the incoming events, and see what happens. Monday :-)

Comment: Use the `STRUCT` keyword for the user element. https://www.confluent.io/blog/data-wrangling-apache-kafka-ksql

Comment: Have a look at https://www.confluent.io/blog/troubleshooting-ksql-part-1. Specifically, if you're saying that there's nothing even after producing new messages (i.e. offset isn't the issue here) then check the KSQL server log for serialisation errors.

Comment: Nope, using the STRUCT keyword does not make it work. `create stream new_events (event_type varchar, project varchar, user struct<name varchar, username varchar>) with (kafka_topic='raw_events', value_format='JSON');`

Comment: Thanks for the link to the troubleshooting page, @RobinMoffatt. That could be helpful :-) 
I was thinking about possible serialization issues as well (and just read that there's an open issue with specifying a serializer for the `kafka-console-consumer` as well: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-2526). Will investigate the logs. It could be that the event messages are stored as strings, and fail to be interpreted as JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the troubleshooting tips at https://www.confluent.io/blog/troubleshooting-ksql-part-1...

- I had data in the source topic
- I had new data*) arriving in the topic
- KSQL was consuming data from the right offset
- Data was matching*) the predicate specified
- I had no deserialization errors in reading the data... reported *)

You'll notice the *)'s though... I found out that the trouble was that I used single quotes in the JSON, whereas valid JSON officially specifies (you guessed it) quotation marks to be only double quotation marks, `"`. I was sent on the wrong track by the fact that some internal representation of the JSON was exported as JSON-with-single-quotes.

So, the correct JSON from my example should be

`{"event_type": "issue",
  "project": "sample",
  "user": {"name": "John Doe", "username": "jdoe"}}`

and everything is fine.

(There's nothing in the log of KSQL server that signals this as a reason for the problem though. Luckily this is not documented here as a potential solution if other people encounter this issue.)

Comment: @RobinMoffatt, not sure if people have mentioned this cause before. If not, you could add something to the troubleshooting guide like "make sure that you're sending valid JSON" :-)